# | was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to locate a file using `dir` and `findstr` to be able to specify the extension and a pattern in the name.

For this, I use the following command:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s *.pm  | findstr /i "MyPattern"') do (set "name=%%a")
```

The question has been mostly answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7769591), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13399026) and in [here](https://superuser.com/q/570760).

But none of them applied to my case.

Comment: None of your linked question (or their answers) handles your problem. You need to escape some special chars inside the `for /f %%a in ('critical part') do ...`. Those chars are `|<>&,=)` (I hope, I didn't forget some): `for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s *.pm ^| findstr /i "MyPattern"') do ...`

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841622/error-was-unexpected-at-this-time-batch-script)

Comment: @Stephan duplicate of [Batch character escaping](//stackoverflow.com/q/6828751)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe (`|`) because it **breaks** the `for` loop just because it is always executed with higher prio. Modify your code like the following:

```bat
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s *.pm  ^| findstr /i "MyPattern"') do (set "name=%%a")
```

and it should work.